# Mejor manera de escribir php combinado con html

Tags: php, html

Me han enseñado dos formas de combinarlos, abriendo y cerrando los trozos de codigo php entre `<?php ?>` y la otra manera seria en una sola etiqueta php poner el html mendiante echo `<etiquetahtml> </etiquetahtml>` .
¿Cual es la mas correcta de usar?

Comment: Esta mas que una pregunta es una opinión, y como tal no hay respuesta correcta o incorrecta, en lo personal siempre combino el código, pero en ocasiones es mejor que todo sea PHP y salidas a HTML, realmente no me preocupo por eso, claro si quieres la opinión de un experto, te recomiendo que veas este reportaje.

Rasmus Lerdorf al creador de PHP y te formes tu propia opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de diferentes maneras, usualmente el despliegue información en la vista se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
<?= $valor ?>
```

Así como el uso de las estructuras de control seria de la siguiente forma

```
<?php if($condicion):?>
    <h1><?= $valor?></h1>
<?php endif?>
```

Esto se hace mas que nada para que no hagas cadenas gigantescas con la estructura de HTML, ejemplo:

```
<?php
   if($condicion){
        echo "<h1>$valor</h1><tabla>...</tabla> ...;
    }
?>
```

Personalmente prefiero la primer opción, ya que con la ayuda de editores de texto puedes ver claramente cuando inicia y termina una sentencia de PHP así como la apertura y cierre de cada etiqueta HTML, pero es a gustos.

Desde luego, si tienes oportunidad mejor usa un gestor de platillas, ya que te optimiza todo el código, desde luego lo transpila a PHP, pero optimiza todo, por lo que se vuelve mas rápido y seguro, uno de los mas usados es [TWIG](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya una manera mejor que la otra. Simplemente utilizas la forma que mejor se adapte al caso en función de cómo tienes estructurado el código. Yo suelo utilizar las dos formas.